# How to create a Firebase user with Google Sign-in from server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'd like to create a user using `admin.auth()` with GoogleAuthProvider.

I've successfully allowed the creation of users with email/password combinations from the back-end, but is the same possible with e.g. Google / Facebook sign-in?

It seems there are providers available for use with `firebase.auth()`:

`var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();`

Is something similar possible with `admin.auth()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as the sign-in libraries for the various authentication providers depend on other libraries that were built to be run in web browser environments, and depend on the user being able to authenticate themselves using UI components that require browser interaction.  In those cases, Firebase Authentication never sees the user's password or other credentials.

Comment: Yeah I thought so - I guess it makes more sense having it on the client. But why do they have methods for creating users with email / password on the backend if it's not possible with other providers? I get that not everyone will use other providers, but in cases that do, the user creation would be done on both front end and back end. Kinda messy is all i thought!

Comment: Maybe I can do both? Just found this documentation - maybe if the client sends an ID token to the server (after the user signs into e.g. Google) and the ID token is verified and thus an account created? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: User/pw auth is available for backends because you are specifying the signin credential (the password) directly in your code. There are no third party libraries required to get a credential.

Comment: You can verify an ID token from the client, but that doesn't let you establish a signin session to perform work as if signed in by that user.  It just tells you if the client provided a valid and fresh ID token.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha - so in that scenario, the client would only ask backend to verify the ID token, and then the client would move on with signing in with the credentials. Hmmm. Okay cool - it makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: The client doesn't have to validate with the server in order to sign in.  The use case for validating a token is typically when the client makes a request directly to the backend, and the backend needs to make sure the user is who they say they are before taking action on their behalf.